# Constraint primary key

Tags: sql, constraints, primary-key

In SQL developer, when PRIMARY KEY is added like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY("ID")
```

In CONSTRAINT is generated with a name like "SYS006321". I need to change this name.

I tried to ADD:

```
CONSTRAINT TABLE_NAME_PK PRIMARY ("ID")
```

but I can't because can be only one PRIMARY KEY. This PRIMARY KEY is used in FOREIGN KEYs in others tables. So if i want to drop this PRIMARY KEY and after that add CONSTRAINT. I have to drop with cascade, so i lose references in FOREIGN KEY. What should I do?

Comment: Be careful when tagging. This appears to be oracle but you have also tagged sql-server. They are NOT the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Oracle you can rename a constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable RENAME CONSTRAINT SYS006321 TO yourNewName;
```

Answer (score 1):

First drop the foreign keys that point to the Primary Key.

Then drop the Primary Key.

Then re-create the primary key with the name you want.

Then re-create the foreign keys.